# Loading Json file and formatting data in Python

Tags: python, json

I have a Json file  from stackoverflow which looks like this:

First Line Represent the **Number of Json object** in this it is 2

```
   2
    {"topic":"electronics","question":"What is the effective differencial effective of this circuit","excerpt":"I'm trying to work out, in general terms, the effective capacitance of this circuit (see diagram: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BS85b.png).  \n\nWhat is the effective capacitance of this circuit and will the ...\r\n        "}
    {"topic":"electronics","question":"Heat sensor with fan cooling","excerpt":"Can I know which component senses heat or acts as heat sensor in the following circuit?\nIn the given diagram, it is said that the 4148 diode acts as the sensor. But basically it is a zener diode and ...\r\n        "}
```

The Content of the Json File is given below

```
 question (string) : The text in the title of the question.
    excerpt (string) : Excerpt of the question body.
    topic (string) : The topic under which the question was posted
```

I am learning ML and I want to parse the data into the format below

```
data[i][0] = contains question
data[i][1] = contains string
data[i][2] = topic
```

so that I can train my classifier. I am new to python or there is some better technique to represent data as i using this as train data 
I have written this code but does not work giving me error:

```
with open("ml.json") as t:
    data = json.load(t)
    print(data)
```

Comment: Have you written any code you could show us that doesn't do what you want it to do? If not, maybe have a look [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).

Comment: Use `json.loads(file)`

Comment: Nope @Rahul, loads reads from a string, load requires an open buffer

Comment: @user5349222 Do you want to just load data from json file into python or do you need help in formating the data?

Comment: @JohnTitusJungao Formatting data would be helpful

Comment: Is that 2 in the first line part of the JSON?

Comment: @cricket_007 First Line represent the number of json object

Comment: I see. Can you try `stackoverflow = json.load(open(filename, 'rb'))` (which is hd1's answer below) and show the result?

Comment: So, that's part of the file? If so, then you can't `json.load` the file because that expects a single JSON Value inside the file... What exactly is the error you are getting?

Comment: when you say `I have a Json file from stackoverflow` do you mean there is a page on stackoverflow that you got this code from?  **If so please link to it.**

Comment: Here is link  which contains the data of stackoverflow [link](https://s3.amazonaws.com/hr-testcases/845/assets/training.json)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that each line (after the first line) contains one object (no object is more than one line), then this function (which returns a generator, and it's memory-efficient) will work.

```
import json

def loadJsonLines(filePath):
    with open(filePath) as fp:
        objCount = int(fp.readline().strip())
        for i in range(objCount):
            line = fp.readline()
            obj = json.loads(line)
            yield obj


if __name__=='__main__':
    import sys
    from pprint import pprint
    for obj in loadJsonLines(sys.argv[1]):
        pprint(obj)

    objList = list(loadJsonLines(sys.argv[1]))
    pprint(objList)
```

Also note that your file **is not a json file**, even though it contains json data in each line (except for first line which is integer), but the whole file is **not json**, so you should not give it a **.json** extension.